# Xaml DataGrid binding from database table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid generated by xaml code like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Resultat}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ></DataGrid>
```

I'm trying to bind this to one table of my Database, Database named BDDInterne and table named Resultat. I have created this database using Entity Framework 5

I have found the property

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
```

but I have only seen examples with datas created on the xaml.cs, not with table from Database.

Hope I gave enough informations. I of course can update my post if something is missing.

If somebody already did this kind of binding, it could help me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

This is the code which generate Resultat:

```
public partial class Resultat
{
    public string NomTable { get; set; }
    public string Groupe_D_alerte { get; set; }
    public string NomChamp { get; set; }
    public string TOTMPMRQ { get; set; }
    public string SiModifie { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTAvant { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTApres { get; set; }
    public string Remarque { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please also share the code to generate/retrieve `Resultat`

Comment: If you want to link directly to a Database, `EntityFramework` is a common way to do so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx

Comment: @Damascus sounds I haven't declared the DataContext, it is one of my errors here I suppose.

Comment: Should be. Make sure you check Visual Studio's Output Window, if bindings failed info will be there

Comment: How can I check this output window? I have never heard speaking about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't bind directly to a database with EF.

How I would approach it (using MVVM pattern):

1. the `DataGrid` on my view would bind `ItemsSource` to a property on my viewmodel, which would be a collection of the class, something like `ResultatCollection`. The columns in that datagrid would bind to properties of that class type.
2. my VM would use a call to a service that utilises EntityFramework to populate that `ResultatCollection`, with a query appropriate for what I'm trying to display. For you, maybe that's everything.

In the viewmodel property declarations:

```
private ObservableCollection<Resultat> _resultatCollection;
public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection
{
    get { return _resultatCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _resultatCollection) return;
        _resultatCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ResultatCollection);
    }
}
```

At some point in the VM I'll make a call to the service that returns my data, and then when it has return the data I'll populate my collection with the results, something like this:

```
ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection(loadOp.Entities);
```

And yes, this all assumes that the DataContext of the view is the viewmodel ...

Comment: Where have I to write `ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection(loadOp.Entities);`? If I write it out of the `public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection` I have lot of errors, and if I write it into, I have A get or set accessor expected. In the other hand, the `RaisePropertyChanged` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: You call your service (maybe in the constructor of your VM, maybe driven by user action). This will normally be asynchronous. In the return from that async (or if you are using await-async pattern you just await the result) you will get the results. For me, those results are return as a loadOp with an Entities property (because I use RIA services). For you they may be in another form.

Comment: So you can't just copy paste my code, I showed it as an example of a few key points. You will need to adapt it to your circumstance after you've answered some questions such as (a) how do I get my results (b) am I using MVVM

Comment: I have finally succeeded in what I wanted to. You gave me very helpfull informations, thanks.